# Resharper Compared with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, resharper

I've heard that [Visual Studio 2010 = Visual Studio 2008 + Resharper](http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/01/19/visual-studio-2010-visual-studio-2008-resharper/).  I'd like to know how true that is.  I don't want to start using Resharper to accomplish superficial things, nor to accomplish things that VS 2010 now already handles.  I'm sure Resharper 5.1.X offers features that VS 2010 does not have, but which of those - in your opinion - represent the true value-adds?  Which of those "truly-valuable" features are available only in the licensed copy?

Comment: Personally I have found that Resharper makes VS 2010 a lot slower and slightly more prone to crashing. Given those negatives, I haven't found that the positives outweigh. Even when a license was provided to me by my employer, I eventually turned off most of its features. However, I have worked with several people who refuse to touch VS without Resharper, so to each his own. To really get the full value from it, I think you really need to master all of its features (especially hot-keys.)

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R5.html

Comment: To me even VS 2010 without Resharper is like stone age.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resharper adds *alot* to VS2010. Just check out [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R5.html) comparison matrix.

> I'm sure Resharper 5.1.X offers features that VS 2010 does not have, but which of those - in your opinion - represent the true value-adds? Which of those "truly-valuable" features are available only in the licensed copy?

All features are available in a non-licensed (demo) copy. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103307/what-is-your-single-favorite-feature-in-resharper) post of what single feature people like about Resharper.

Answer (score 6):

This is a 'joke' based on the fact that Microsoft supposedly released [a screenshot of 2010 with ReSharper UI visible](http://jameskovacs.com/2009/01/19/visual-studio-2010-visual-studio-2008-resharper/).

VS.Net 2010 definitely does not go any way towards making ReSharper redundant!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is slightly off topic. However, as a response to whether VS2010 is making Resharper redundant;

I've upgraded ReSharper from 5.1 to 6 roughly 1 month after release. It got slower. To the point when I have to Suspend it occasionally - particularly when doing lots of work on JavaScript, CSS or larger template files (Razor). Sad thing is it just gets slower.

At home, I'm using just a plain VS2010 Professional without any add-ons. And it just feels like a breeze - everything is responsive and there are no hiccups when copy pasting (during manual re factoring). Admittedly at work I have T4MVC and Chirpy installed along Resharper.

Feature wise, what I'm using in ReSharper:

- Auto usings (alt + Enter)
- Cannot use auto include references as it gets it wrong 80% of the time
- Refactor: initialize member variable from constructor parameter
- Refactor: replace with LinQ expression

Sadly that's about it. In light of this, because of the slowdowns I'm considering dropping ReSharper altogether. This is my grievances:

- Delay every time I copy a piece of code in order to move it - anything from half a second to 2 seconds. Please note the delay increases with project / solution size
- Auto completion in JavaScript and CSS: 95% of the time it inserts code I don't want - in particular () after selecting an object property. Getting fed up having to delete the brackets each time
- class name and id suggestion. This happens in CSS as well as Razor template. It will try to insert an existing class name / html id when you are in fact creating a new one. It will do this whenever you press space. Instead you have to press escape.
- Pasting code. Again when refactoring manually and code is moved from one class to another it will keep pestering you with all missing usings. First you have to press Escape for "Insert all missing usings" and then once for every occurrence of a class without a reference. Usually you want to change something upon pasting code but this feature makes code unreadable with all the popups.

I could go on abut the things I find annoying with ReSharper. Not trying to offend any die-hard productivity tool enthusiasts, bottom line is VS2010 is on it's own a very decent IDE and a lot of ReSharper features can be found within it - though not always intuitively.

If you are just learning C# ReSharper is a great tool that helps you organize your code better. But if you've been working with .NET for a while you will most likely find it intrusive and hampering productivity on some occasions.

Comment: The "auto usings" feature, through "ctrl-.", is already available in VS2010.  One more nail in the coffin, given your viewpoint.

Comment: Good point. The VS implementation just works a bit differently - you have to right click  missing reference. It doesn't do "auto include reference" which is a good thing because you can't accidentally include a /bin/debug reference this way.

Answer (score 3):

Re#er still got much stronger code check and refactoring options.